# Python inverting dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to invert the rows of a yfinance dataframe, using iloc but it doesn't work

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

s1 = 'AAPL'

a=yf.download(s1, period = '1d', interval = '1m')
a.iloc[::-1]

print(a)
```

output:

```
2020-08-17 15:56:00-04:00  459.274994  459.320007  458.829987  458.920013  458.920013   149501
2020-08-17 15:57:00-04:00  458.920013  458.950012  458.589996  458.890015  458.890015   147451
2020-08-17 15:58:00-04:00  458.859985  458.889587  458.390015  458.660004  458.660004   132868
2020-08-17 15:59:00-04:00  458.700012  458.850006  458.000000  458.329987  458.329987   442095
```

I'm looking for the time to go from latest at the top to earliest at the bottom.

Comment: Is this what you want?  `df.sort_index(ascending=False)`

Comment: `sort_values` or `sort_index` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually inverting the data frame using the code `a.iloc [:: - 1]`, but you can't see the expected result **because you haven't assigned it to variable a.**

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

s1 = 'AAPL'

a=yf.download(s1, period = '1d', interval = '1m')

print(a.iloc[::-1])
```

or

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
    
s1 = 'AAPL'
    
a=yf.download(s1, period = '1d', interval = '1m')

a = a.iloc[::-1] 

print(a)
```

You will see the output as follows:

```
                                 Open        High  ...   Adj Close   Volume
Datetime                                           ...                     
2020-08-17 15:59:00-04:00  458.700012  458.850006  ...  458.329987   442095
2020-08-17 15:58:00-04:00  458.859985  458.889587  ...  458.660004   132868
2020-08-17 15:57:00-04:00  458.920013  458.950012  ...  458.890015   147451
2020-08-17 15:56:00-04:00  459.274994  459.320007  ...  458.920013   149501
2020-08-17 15:55:00-04:00  459.329987  459.359985  ...  459.290009   155676
...                               ...         ...  ...         ...      ...
2020-08-17 09:34:00-04:00  462.399994  462.399994  ...  461.529999   198725
2020-08-17 09:33:00-04:00  462.814087  462.929993  ...  462.410004   223107
2020-08-17 09:32:00-04:00  463.600006  463.600006  ...  462.863800   267131
2020-08-17 09:31:00-04:00  463.429993  463.940002  ...  463.554993   198041
2020-08-17 09:30:00-04:00  464.250000  464.350006  ...  463.399994  1214226

[389 rows x 6 columns]
```